# gradual button color change on android

Tags: android, button, background-color

I want gradually change button color, after click on it. I mean, button must have, for example next set of colors: by default - dark dark blue, then dark blue, then blue, then light blue, and in the end - the lightest blue. This is only example, really I want to change button color in cycle, like in the next code. But, I can't understand, why it doesn't show intermediate colors. It shows only first color, and the last one.

How to improve this?

```
public class ActivityExample extends Activity {
private changeColorBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_animations);

    changeColorBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_change_color);

    changeColorBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    changeColorBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeButtonColor(v);

        }
    });

}

private void changeButtonColor(View v) {
    // How many intermediate color will be, and delay in millisecond between them
    int count = 20, delay = 100;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        try {

            int color = ((ColorDrawable) changeColorBtn.getBackground())
                    .getColor();
            int blue = Color.blue(color), red = Color.red(color), green = Color.green(color);
            changeColorBtn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(red+10, green+5, blue+3));

            Thread.sleep(delay);
        } catch (InterruptedException inE) {
        }
    }

}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: I am guessing the view is not redrawn when your loop is executing. I would recommend using an animation class.

Comment: You could try and request the view be redrawn in your current loop but it would not be as smooth or consistent as an animation.

Comment: What is your minimum android version?

Comment: Just a remark: you are calling `Thread.sleep()` on the UI thread, it will cause your application to lag...

Comment: I have minSdkVersion="13"

Comment: So, as I understand, I should use animation for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem using [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html). You can follow next step:

- Create an xml file in the drawable folder, and write there something like:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/color1" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/color2" />
</transition>
```

`

- Then, in your xml for this button (or another element / View) you should reference this [TransitionDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/TransitionDrawable.html) in the `android:background` attribute.
- Also you should have colors stored as resources: for this, you have to create an xml like following:

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="color1">#990000</color>
    <color name="color2">#cc3311</color>
</resources>
```

`

and save this xml file in the /res/values/ folder,  name the xml as color.xml.

- And initiate the transition in code:

`

```
int durationMillis = 2000;
TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) changeColorBtn.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(durationMillis);
```

`

**This is helped me, I hope it will be useful for others.**